# Apply for higher quota for Google Tasks API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

Our quota for Google Task API "per day" has been exhausted. When we try and increase the quota, it says you need to apply for higher quota by "clicking here". However the Quotas page under IAMs does not allow you to apply for an increase.

How do we apply for an increase in quota limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/tasks/pricing?hl=en) about `Google Tasks API` to understand how the limit works.

### How to increase the quota limit:

- Link a [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account) to your [Google Cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)
- Search and enable the `Google Tasks API` in the [library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?) of the API Console
- Click on `Manage` > `Quotas` to see your usage.
- Go to [Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=sheets.googleapis.com) and filter by `Google Tasks API`, there is a link on the last window.
- Select all the quotas that you want to modify by clicking on its `Limit name` and then on `Global`
- Click on `Edit quotas` and write a description of your request including the intent of the quota usage, future growth plans, region or zone spread, and any additional requirements or dependencies.

Comment: When you edit the quota who is the "service provider" that the request is sent to?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to setup and assign a billing account before you can make a request - this wasn't clear in the documentation / "apply for higher quota" pages.

Comment: Me too, but I don't know what should do next

Comment: Follow instructions shared by @fullfine